# CSS, DIV with position: absolute overlaps <p> text

Tags: html, css

So I've been told (maybe this is wrong) that if you want to overide (go beyond) the margins of a parent div simply make the child position:absolute.  The problem with this is that it will overlap text that is set below that div.

Is there a way to;

1. Override the margins of the parent div and have that div still push down the adjacent text?
2. Can this be executed by not applying a margin-top: to the first block of text? This solution seems sloppy, the layout would blow up while in mobile view.

Thanks for you help / opinion on this one.

The page in question can be found [here](http://www.gridviper.com/phelan/about/).

Comment: "Maring" is supposed to be margin, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the image background for the div has the position absolute and put the image as a background for the parent div with the following selector:

```
.entry-content {
    padding: 0 40px 40px;
    background: url('http://www.gridviper.com/phelan/wp-content/uploads/back-blue-top4.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 219px;
}
```

and change the absolute div css to be as the following:

```
 .content-masthead {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 219px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few hinds to help you fixing this:

This this not the parent, but the first positioned ancestor (with position other than null, can be "relative").

You can define the size of this element in percentage relative to this ancestor.

You can use padding instead of margin to keep the space.